# Connecting RestAPI Slim framework to Android application

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, slim

I am new Android Developer, and I am trying to connect MySQL through my android application with Rest API that is written in Slim framework, so can you please explain how to write REST API using Slim framework???

Comment: you mean you already have API written in SLIM PHP Framework and you want to connect with it from android ???

Comment: Can you please rephrase that question so it is a little more clear? What I understand is that your System is built of a) Server side: MySQL DB served through a REST API built with SlimFramework. b) Client side: Android client. Now you want to "connect" what to where?

Comment: I'm trying to have connecting between Slim and Application, and use the methods that uses in Slim as POST, GET,PUT and DELETE, because I'm using MySQL to have DB throw the Internet

Answer (score 1):

From the requirement you mentioned so far, Its seems that you want to send/receive the data to/from your android app which is stored in MSQL database (running on some server).

Hence what you need to do is,

1. Write your REST APIs in [SLIM PHP FRAMEWORK](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/),
2. Call them from your android app

so that they can be used to store/retrieve the data to/from your MSQL database.

I will explain evrything in short-

**Slim Framework**

> Slim is a PHP micro framework that helps you quickly write simple yet
>   powerful web applications and APIs.

*In easy words, its the set of functions/functionalities that can be used for writing REST APIs.*
So, you will have to write your REST APIs using those set of functionalities.

A simple **Slim 3** app contains routes that respond to specific HTTP requests. Below is a route which will invoke a callback function on a HTTP POST request-

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/user/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $user = array();
    //$user will be an array of post parameters
    $user = $request->getParsedBody();
    $response->getBody()->write(/*a json string*/);
    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

If you google about how to write rest api for android, you will get good SLIM tutorials for writing rest apis like these->

1. http://www.slimframework.com/docs/

Slim will act as a middleware here->

> **[Android App] <--> [SLIM PHP FRAMEWORK] <--> [MySQL Database Server]**

Above, it shows how data will flow from your app to db server and vice versa.

Once you successfully write your APIs you just need to call them from your android code. You must be using something like [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json) to do network communication in android.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, I already did Slim file, but I did not know how to connect the android application to the php file

can you please more explain how to connect the php file to android application, because I google how to connect a lot but I didn't find the answer

Comment: its totally upto you... how you call your rest api in android, there are so many methods, libraries out there... you just need to google it and figure out which suits you the best.. I have mentioned one above in my answer.